# Using IInputFilter in MonoForAndroid

Tags: xamarin.android, input-filtering

I need to implement a RegExpInputFilter as an IInputFilter in Mono for Android but I do not understand how to do it. Is there some guidance on how to implement Java interfaces somewhere that explains this in detail? Or even better, has anyone written their own IInputFilter in Mono for Android that can share the code or just some tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IInputFilter is already part of the Mono for Android framework

It is part of the Android.Text namespace

http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Text.IInputFilter

```
class RegExInputFilter : Java.Lang.Object, IInputFilter
{
    public Java.Lang.ICharSequence FilterFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence source, int start, int end, ISpanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
       //filter
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, this is the first time I implement a Java interface in Mono for Android so I did not realize that I should derive from Java.Lang.Object so I was trying to figure out how to provide the IntPtr Handle. Do I create instances of my class with a regular C# new or do I need to use some JavaNew thingy?

Comment: You can instantiate the class with the regular C# new. Implementing Java.Lang.Object just ensures that an Android Callable Wrapper is created. More info on this here http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Android_Callable_Wrappers